# regular expression for entering wrong address and restrict user using javascript or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex

I tried the piece of code to restrict user if the address is wrongly entered as shown below 
sample address: #23 78/54, A-31 Nand Jyot Indl Estate, Andheri- Kurla Road, Saki Naka (**allowed**)

14/18, Loha Bhavan, P D Mello Rd, Chinch Bunder, mumbai (**allowed**)

only ".....", ",,,,", "----" (**not allowed**)

```
 $("#" + (idOfElement)).on("keypress keyup", function (e) {
                        this.value = this.value
                            //.replace(/[^\..]/g,'')
                            .replace(/(^[\d#\w]+)/g, '$1')
                            .replace(/(\s[1-9A-Za-z\/#-]*)./g, '$1');

                    });
```

I want the user allowed to enter numbers, '#', '/', '-', space, and alphabets only, and if they enter any other special characters it shouldn't allow them to do so.

code given below is working fine for number with decimal upto two position. similarly i want to do the same for address.

below code allows 12345.67

it doesn't allow 23.4565, 23289.499999

```
//for numbers with decimal point upto two position
$("#" + (idOfElement)).on("keypress keyup blur", function (e) {
                        this.value = this.value
                            .replace(/[^\d.]/g, '')
                            .replace(/(^[\d]+)([\d]*)/g, '$1')
                            .replace(/(\..*)\./g, '$1')
                            .replace(/(\.[\d]{2})./g, '$1');
                        if ((e.which != 46 || $(this).val().indexOf('.') != -1) && (e.which < 48 || e.which > 57)) {
                            e.preventDefault();
                        }
```

I also want the user to enter only alphabets with space and numbers only.

sample data: toothpaste 200g (**allowed**)

shampoo..(**not allowed**)

shampoo (with any other special character like !,?,_,~)(**not allowed**)

Comment: Have you considered using the `pattern` attribute on input fields?  See [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/search#pattern)

Comment: I don't let user to enter any special character, that is, while giving input, if user user tries to enter something that's not allowed, it is not entered in the input field. pattern attribute checks with pattern only after we try to submit the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below code sample. Also please find fiddle for same in comment.

```
<input type="text" id="addressID">

  $(document).ready(function(){
  $("input").bind('input', function(e) {
  var str = $("#addressID").val();
  var re = new RegExp(/^[ A-Za-z0-9\/#-]*$/g);
  if (re.test(str)) {
          //alert('valid');

    } else {
       alert("Invalid address, only alphanumeric values and '/','#','-' allowed");
       $("#addressID").val($("#addressID").val().slice(0, -1));
    }
});
});
```

Comment: Fiddle link for above answer https://jsfiddle.net/shivpatne/u27mvb95

Comment: If it works accept the answer and upvote too, if it doesn't work let me know the issue.

Comment: is this regex correct for address, can you help me out with this

Comment: Yes, I have created regex exact as per your requirement. It will allow to enter alphanumeric values and only special characters that you mentioned in question "#","/" and "-"